# Dynamic ng-repeat using an expression

Tags: angularjs

I've made a key/value object named items and was wondering if the syntax I have below is wrong.. Or is the below not possible in Angular? (Or is a better way possible?)

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things">
  <span ng-repeat="item in items.{{thing}}">
    {{item.id}}
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: What about `<span ng-repeat="item in items[think]">`, you are simply accessing a property within an object

Comment: That did it thanks @MikeVranckx  !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mike said, try

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things">
  <span ng-repeat="item in items[thing]">
    {{item.id}}
  </span>
</div>
```